# What is the best and fatest way to insert json data into elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, insert, bulk

I have many json files (about 200 per day, each file contains more than 300 000 lines) that i need to insert into elasticsearch index.

I'm looking for a way to say to elasticsearch to get each json file in a folder, and put each row into an index mapping the correct fields. And I must do it fast (best will be less than 30 min.)

Is it possible to "industrialize" this process with filebeat/ logstash or another one ?

I tried a simple bulk insert using elasticsearch .net and nest api but it takes too many times to do it (about 3/4 min per file)

I did some test with filebeat but all I achieved is to insert the json data into the field message of a log..In my case, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

actually, Filebeat can decode JSON lines: [docu](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-config-json)

if you are on Unix (cygwin) you could use a simple command to add JSON lines from a file to index:

```
$ cat books.json
{"title":"Book #1", "author":"Author #1"}
{"title":"Book #2", "author":"Author #2"}
{"title":"Book #3", "author":"Author #3"}
{"title":"Book #4", "author":"Author #4"}
{"title":"Book #5", "author":"Author #5"}

$ sed -e '/^..*/i {"index":{}}' -e '$a\\n' books.json | curl 'http://localhost:9200/books/_bulk?pretty&filter_path=off' --data-binary @- -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s
{ }
```

ES will generate _id for every document automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I used json decode in filebeat and it works. Now, I can see my data (Name,Unit,Value,geo and Time) but I also see all another logs fields that I don't want in my mapping.
[image]
Also, The geo data is not recognize as geo point type. Is there something to add in config ?

I tried to do my own template but it seems that filebeat don't take it.
btw: the bulk with filebeat :

20 json files with total lines around 5 millions takes 19 minutes !! IS it normal ? for me, it seems very very slow..

Same files with bulk insert in c# is about 3/4 minutes.